# How to submit a local html in form C# uwp that refers to a native code as submition?

Tags: c#, html, forms, uwp

I have this form code in my HTML file.

```
<form name="myForm" id="formID" action="#" style="width: 344px"> 
<input name="address" type="text" value="" maxlength="17" style="width: 167px"/></b>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Generate" onclick="myFunc(this.form)" style="width: 118px" />
<br></b>
<input name="result" type="text" maxlength="8" style="width: 167px" />
</form>
```

"myFunc" is a function that does some work on the "address" and exports its result into "result".

I want to write a code in C# (UWP) to send the address to this file and get the result, all on the background without any extra screen to be shown.

Can I use HttpRequest or HttpClient or something? If yes, how?

Comment: Why do you need to send your data to form and get result? Is processing directly without a form not an option in the scope of your project?

Comment: @avk-naidu The html file is not mine and the function does such complicated mathematical operations. I don't have any idea how to process directly and get the result from that function.

Comment: There is something called [Chakra](https://www.eternalcoding.com/?p=1932)  using which you can execute `JS` from `C#` without a `WebView`, I personally never Used it but heard this is a very efficient package. Give it a try.

Comment: @avk-naidu But the function is not a single javascript file and it's written inside the html file. I wanna know if there is a way without bothering to make a javascript file and using another extension.

Comment: @avk-naidu And thanks for the answer btw. I'll try Chakra and see if I can get it to work.